# lyx inserting endframe in the wrong place

Tags: beamer, lyx

I create a slide using the beamer template in LyX using the following steps:

1. Set environment to Frame
2. Edit the Frame title to "Test"
3. Press the right arrow and enter, change environment to itemize

Lyx automatically inserts `\end{frame}` after the `\begin{frame}{test}` without inserting my `itemize` environment in between. If instead I simply type a bunch of text instead of an itemize environment then things are fine.

I am using LyX 2.1. This did not happen in previous versions of LyX.

I do not include MWE as I would like somebody to repeat my steps to see if they are seeing the same issue.

Comment: I believe this is by design. Take a look at the Beamer manual (Help > Specific Manuals > Beamer Presentations). It's extremely informative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see the same, but hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key after starting the `itemize`, and it is moved within the frame. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> or Edit --> Increase list depth does the same.

The manual (Help --> Specific manuals --> Beamer presentations) does mention this, although without specific mention of lists:

[image]

Comment: yes i have noticed this as well. this might be a bug or simply how the 2.1 version of LyX works, i cannot tell...

Comment: @Alex If you suspect a bug, ask in the LyX mailing list, or simply add an issue in the bug tracker.

Comment: good idea - i'll mark you answer as correct